# Delivery address in a e-commerce system when the order is finalized issues?

Tags: mysql, sql

Well i'm doing a e-commerce system and i got some questions,

Lets me explain the user can have manu address then before order is finalized the user will choose a these address, after the order is finalized the user can't change the address? it's correct way to do it? if yes i can't use foreign key of address in order table, isn't? i need to put the address in a normal field then if the user change the address it will not change in this order, right?

Someone could help me with it?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I.e:

```
tb_order

order_id
address_id

tb_address

address_id
field01...
field02...
...
```

Well when the order is finalized it will be insert in tb_order, can u see the problem? example if the user make a order then the same user change the address and make another buy the first buy will be changed also, the correct way could be:

```
tb_order

order_id
address_field01
address_field02
...

tb_address

address_id
field01...
field02...
...
```

without foreign key then if u user change the address no problem and the address could be change in admin.

My question is if it's correct way to do?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.